# Iterating through a list of lists of 3-tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

`plusOne :: [[(Int, Int, Int)]] -> [[(Int, Int, Int)]]`

Given a list of lists of 3-tuples.
If I want to iterate through the list and +1 to the Int values, how should I approach this? I'm not sure if this is a scenario where Maps should be used or not.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: `plusOne = map (map (+1)) `?

Comment: Divide and conquer. First write a fun tion to manipulate one list element. Then combine it with a function that manipulates lists.

Comment: You might want to introduce a type to make your function signature more readable. For example `String` is a type for `[Char]`.

Comment: @arrowd You can't `(+1)` a 3-tuple, but you can indeed use `map (map f)` for a suitable `f`.

Answer (score 6):

Split the functions. The lists are easy; one `map` each. But tuples don't traverse the way they do in e.g. Python, so they require unpacking to access the elements; this is possible with generic programming but far easier with pattern matching. Tuples can hold fields of varying types, so something like `map` couldn't access all of them. We can make our own map-analogue for triples specifically:

```
map3t :: (x -> y) -> (x, x, x) -> (y, y, y)
map3t f (a, b, c) = (f a, f b, f c)
```

Now we can inspect each level of our type and handle it separately:

```
op :: Int -> Int
op = (+1)
t3 :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
t3 = map3t op
lt3 :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
lt3 = map t3
llt3 :: [[(Int, Int, Int)]] -> [[(Int, Int, Int)]]
llt3 = map lt3
```

This is not recursion, although `map` may be implemented using recursion ([`Data.List.map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) is). Each function calls a different function for the inner level.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a not very generic way of how we can use map to access nested lists,which also can be matched on 3tuples with a lambda function:

```
fun :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [[(a, b, c)]] -> [[(a, b, c)]]
fun xs = map (map(\(x,y,z) -> (x+1,y+1,z+1))) xs
```

Pros: En easy and understandable oneliner to solve a specific problem

Cons: Not generic for the function applied to the elements, can become fuzzy and out of hand with more complex and bigger input structures.

Mapping with a hard coded function forcing you to make a new map for each operation. So a better way in that case would be to refactor the function itself, ie :

```
fun2 f xs = map (map(op f)) xs
    where
    op f' (x,y,z) = (f' x,f' y, f' z)
```

Making `op` a function to which you can give an operation for the specific type.

Making the signature for the function more generic on the types of operations: (Notice here that we can no longer be sure of the type of `x,y,z`, which before were numerics (because of the `+1` operation) giving us a more generic version of the function, but also making us more responsible of matching the types correctly, no string operations on integers etc.)

```
fun2 :: (t -> c) -> [[(t, t, t)]] -> [[(c, c, c)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a proper functor to wrap your tuples.

```
data Three a = Three {getThree :: (a, a, a)} deriving (Show, Functor)
```

If you don't want to use the `DeriveFunctor` extension, the definition is simple:

```
instance Functor Three where
  fmap f (Three (x, y, z)) = Three (f x, f y, f z)
```

Then you can simply define `plusOne` as

```
>>> plusOne = let f = getThree . fmap (+1) . Three in fmap (fmap f)
```

where `f` is a function that wraps a 3-tuple, maps `(+1)` over each element, and unwraps the result. This gets mapped over your list of lists:

```
> x = [[(1, 2, 3), (4,5,6)], [(7,8,9)]]
> plusOne x
[[(2,3,4),(5,6,7)],[(8,9,10)]]
```

---

You can also use `Data.Functor.Compose` to eliminate one of the levels of `fmap` (or, at least hide it behind another set of names to break up the monotony):

```
> getCompose . fmap (getThree . fmap (+1) . Three) . Compose $ x
[[(2,3,4),(5,6,7)],[(8,9,10)]]
```

We've applied the same pattern of wrapping/fmaping/unwrapping twice. We can abstract that away with a helper function

```
-- wrap, map, and unwrap
wmu pre post f = post . fmap f . pre

plusOne = wmu Compose getCompose $ wmu Three getThree $ (+1)
```

---

One might notice a similarity between `wmu` and `dimap` (specialized to `(->)`):

```
wmu pre post = dimap pre post . fmap
```

---

Everything is even simpler if you can replace the generic tuple with a custom product type in the first place.

```
data Triplet a = Triplet a a a

-- Can be derived as well
instance Functor Triplet where
    fmap f (Triplet x y z) = Triplet (f x) (f y) (f z)

plusOne :: [[Triplet Int]] -> [[Triplet Int]]
plusOne = fmap (fmap (fmap (+1)))
```